# Python logging: FileHandler when in mode 'w' not working but in mode 'a' works fine

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python `2.7.5` under Windows when `FileHandler` is in mode `'w'` (truncate file before writing) handler does NOT write only last line. When in mode `'a'` everything is fine.

My `logging.conf` file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('generator.log', 'a', 'utf8', 0)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=[ %(asctime)s ] [ %(name)s ] [ %(levelname)-5s ] - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

My `oracle.py` file:

```
__author__ = 'wbar'
import cx_Oracle
from contextlib import closing
import logging


class Connector(object):
    __connection__ = None
    __user_name__ = None
    __password__ = None
    __tns_name__ = None
    __logger__ = None

    def get_connection(self, auto_connect=True):
        if auto_connect and not self.__connection__:
            self.__logger__.info(u'Connecting into Oracle: %s@%s', self.__user_name__, self.__tns_name__)
            self.__connection__ = cx_Oracle.connect(
                u'%s/%s@%s' % (self.__user_name__, self.__password__, self.__tns_name__))
        return self.__connection__

    def __init__(self, user_name, password, tns_name):
        self.__user_name__ = user_name
        self.__password__ = password
        self.__tns_name__ = tns_name
        self.__logger__ = logging.getLogger('OracleConnector')
        self.__logger__.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())

    def __del__(self):
        self.close_connection()

    def close_connection(self):
        connection = self.get_connection(auto_connect=False)
        if connection:
            self.__logger__.info(u'Closing connection with Oracle: %s@%s', self.__user_name__, self.__tns_name__)
            connection.close()

    def execute(self, sql):
        with closing(self.get_connection().cursor()) as cursor:
            self.__logger__.debug(u'Executing: %s', sql)
            cursor.execute(sql)
            return cursor.fetchall()
```

And finally my main file `generator.py`:

```
__author__ = 'wbar'
import logging
import logging.config

logging.FileHandler
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

from oracle import Connector as OracleConnector
DATABASE = OracleConnector(user_name=u'foo', password=u'bar', tns_name=u'db_local')

for line in DATABASE.execute('select * from dual'):
    print(line[0])

logger = logging.getLogger('root')

logger.debug('DEBUG')
logger.info('INFO')
logger.error('ERROR')
```

When in mode `'a'` log file looks like:

```
[ 2013-11-13 17:15:25,608 ] [ OracleConnector ] [ INFO  ] - Connecting into Oracle: pms_test@db_impaq_local
[ 2013-11-13 17:15:25,727 ] [ OracleConnector ] [ DEBUG ] - Executing: select * from dual
[ 2013-11-13 17:15:25,730 ] [ root ] [ DEBUG ] - DEBUG
[ 2013-11-13 17:15:25,730 ] [ root ] [ INFO  ] - INFO
[ 2013-11-13 17:15:25,730 ] [ root ] [ ERROR ] - ERROR
[ 2013-11-13 17:15:25,734 ] [ OracleConnector ] [ INFO  ] - Closing connection with Oracle: pms_test@db_impaq_local
```

When in mode `'w'` log file looks like:

```
[ 2013-11-13 17:06:24,239 ] [ OracleConnector ] [ INFO  ] - Closing connection with Oracle: pms_test@db_impaq_local
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the exact problem? You first state that *when FileHandler is in mode 'w' (truncate file before writing) handler does NOT write only last line* but then show us a log with only one line (the last one).

Comment: @MartijnPieters logger will open file EVERYTIME to write entry? Does it open file once when creating `FileHandler` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `logging` module registers an [`atexit` shutdown hook](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) closing all handlers. This closes the open `'w'` file object when Python exits.

However, your `oracle.Connector()` class has a `__del__` method, which is *also* called when Python exits. Python calls `atexit` before globals are cleaned up, so the exact order of operations here is:

1. `logging`'s `atexit` hook is called, file is closed.
2. `oracle.Connector().__del__()` is called, which calls `self.__logger__.info()`. This **reopens** the closed file handler to log, truncating the file.

To prevent this, explicitly close your connector *before* exiting Python:

```
DATABASE.close_connection()
```

Comment: Can You provide solution for closing this connection without using `__del__` method that will be executed automatically ?

Comment: @WBAR: not log when closing in the `__del__` hook, perhaps? Or just use the `'a'` append mode.

Comment: I added `asap` parameter into close_connection :)  THX! MAN!